# Proof Critique - There's no function that is continuous at all rational and discontinuous at all irrational

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

*Claim.* If $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is continuous at all rational points, we can find an irrational point at which $f(x)$ is also continuous.

*Proof.* Let $r_1 \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ be arbitrary. Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $r_1$, there exists a $\phi_1 > 0$ such that for all $x\in ( r_1-\phi_1,r_1+\phi_1)$, we have $\left|f(x) - f(r_1)\right| < 1/2$. Let $$\delta_1 = min(\frac{\phi_1}{2} , 1).$$ Then for all $x\in [r_1-\delta_1,r_1+\delta_1]$, we have $\left|f(x) - f(r_1)\right| < 1/2$. Then for all $x_1,x_2\in[r_1-\delta_1, r_1+\delta_1]$, we have $$\left|f(x_1) - f(x_2)\right| \leq \left|f(x_1) - f(r_1)\right| + \left|f(r_1) - f(x_2)\right| < 1.$$

Let $r_2 \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (r_1-\delta_1, r_1+\delta_1)$ be arbitrary.
Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $r_2$, there exists a $\phi_2 > 0$ such that for all $x\in(r_2 - \phi_2 , r_2 + \phi_2)$, we have $\left|f(x) - f(r_2)\right|<1/4$. Let 
$$\delta_2 =min\left(\frac{\phi_2}{2}, \frac{1}{4},r_2-(r_1-\delta_1), -r_2+(r_1+\delta_1)\right)$$ then for all $x\in[r_2 - \delta_2 , r_2 + \delta_2]$, we have $\left|f(x) - f(r_2)\right|<1/4$. Then we have a $\delta_2\leq 1/4$ such that $(r_1-\delta_1)\leq (r_2 - \delta_2) \leq (r_2+\delta_2)\leq(r_1+\delta_1)$. Also for all $x_1,x_2 \in [r_2 - \delta_2,r_2+\delta_2]$, we have  $$\left|f(x_1) - f(x_2)\right| \leq \left|f(x_1) - f(r_2)\right| + \left|f(r_2) - f(x_2)\right| < \frac{1}{2}.$$

Recursively, let $r_{n+1} \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (r_n-\delta_n, r_n+\delta_n)$ be arbitrary. 
Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $r_{n+1}$, there exists a $\phi_{n+1}$ such that for all $x\in (r_{n+1} - \phi_{n+1},r_{n+1}+\phi_{n+1})$, we have $\left|f(x) - f(r_{n+1})\right|<\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$. 
Let $$\delta_{n+1} = min(\frac{\phi_{n+1}}{2},\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},r_{n+1}- (r_n-\delta_n),-r_{n+1}+(r_n+\delta_n))$$ then for all $x\in[r_{n+1} - \delta_{n+1} , r_{n+1} + \delta_{n+1}]$, we have $\left|f(x) - f(r_{n+1})\right|<\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$. We also have a $\delta_{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ such that $(r_n-\delta_n)\leq (r_{n+1} - \delta_{n+1}) \leq (r_{n+1}+\delta_{n+1})\leq(r_n+\delta_n)$. We also have that for all $x_1,x_2 \in [r_{n+1} - \delta_{n+1},r_{n+1}+\delta_{n+1}]$, $$\left|f(x_1) - f(x_2)\right| \leq \left|f(x_1) - f(r_{n+1})\right| + \left|f(r_{n+1})- f(x_2)\right| < \frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Then we have 
$$(r_1-\delta_1)\leq (r_2 - \delta_2) \leq (r_3 - \delta_3) \leq \cdots \leq (r_3+\delta_3) \leq (r_2+\delta_2)\leq(r_1+\delta_1)$$

According to Nested Interval Theorem, we have $$\exists! x \ x\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}[r_n-\delta_n, r_n+\delta_n]$$

Let a be such x.

By such construction, we can see that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$$

By Dedekind Cut, we know that $a$ is irrational.

Thus we find a irrational point where $f(x)$ is continuous.

---

I used $\delta = \frac{\phi}{2}$ because in the definition of limit, the it's "for all x in $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$", while for here I need it to be closed interval.

I constructed the nested intervals in a similar way as constructing a Cauchy sequence. Is it clear that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$?

I used Dedekind cut to prove the unique a is irrational, but I don't know if I need to be more specified.

Comment: Doesn't it suffice to prove that for every interval of rational numbers there exist an irrational number?

Comment: @shaihorowitz I think to prove the statement in the title I only need to prove for a small interval. Because if there is such function on R, then there is such a function on [0,1]. By contraposition I can prove the statement in the title.

Comment: my claim is easier to prove but it's not sufficient due to popcorn function

Comment: @shaihorowitz ohh I misunderstood you. I thought about that, but that will require every $r_n-\delta_n$ to be rational...

Comment: or to have a rational approximations

Comment: @shaihorowitz yea that make sense. But why did you say that it's not sufficient?

Comment: there exist functions continuous at every irrational point and discontinuous at rationals even though the same dense property holds such as the popcorn function

Comment: @shaihorowitz that's different. The popcorn function is continuous at every irrationals but the one I'm disproving is continuous at every rationals

Comment: yeah but I'm stating my density argument is non sufficient

Comment: @shaihorowitz yeah you are right. I'll try to exclude every rational outside the interval and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is nice. I didn't comb it carefully, but it seems to be right. It isn't obvious to me that you have constructed a Dedekind cut, so I would perhaps recommend providing more detail there.

The other critique I have would be where you said:

$$\exists! x \ x\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}[r_n-\delta_n, r_n+\delta_n].$$

I would change it to:

$$\exists! a \text{ such that } \ a\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}[r_n-\delta_n, r_n+\delta_n].$$

It makes it less confusing when you later say $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$ because there is no longer 2 uses of the letter $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking that no one would bother reading my long laborious proof. By the way, is it plausible to use Dedekind cut here? I haven't learned it a lot. The only thing I know is that it fills the gaps between rationals.